# Unable to display PDF from external url

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, routes

i have an external api's url: "**/loc/api.php/downloadfacture/" i have to add 2 parameters $numsoc et $numfacture to be abble to display a pdf file.

I'm using Guzzle as http client.

I only can access to var $numsoc and $numfactures from my vue.blade (due to another api parse by the foreach $data as $d)

Problem: i can see in my log file that the url looks good
=> 2019-04-24 09:49:19 - GET downloadfacture /downloadfacture/2795 numfact=1218100031&numsoc=12 but i'm not able to display anything.

Laravel routing or wrong controller method, i can't see my mistakes, need your help please to understand the right method.

Thanks!

this is the controller

```
public function downloadfactures($numsoc, $numfact)
    {
        $urid = config('params.base_uri.loc_download');
        $user = null;
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $user = Auth::user()->code_clt;
        }

        $client = new Client(['base_uri' => $urid]);
        $response = $client->request('GET', $user, [
            'query' => [
                'numsoc' => $numsoc,
                'numfact' => $numfact,
                'id' => '',
            ],
        ]);

        $data = $response->getBody()->getContents();
        header('Content-type: application/pdf');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=report.pdf');
        echo $data;
    }
```

vue.blade.php

```
@if(isset($data ))
                    @foreach($data as $d)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$d->Contrat}}</td>
                            <td>{{$d->NomClient}}</td>
                            <td>{{$d->Conducteur}}</td>
                            <td>{{$d->Vehicule}}</td>
                            <td>{{$d->Annee}}</td>
                            <td>{{$d->Mois}}</td>
                            <td>{{$d->Dossier}}</td>
                            <td>{{$d->FactureNum}}</td>
                            <td>{{$d->Mht}}</td>
                            <td class="table-light"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" title="pdf"></i></a></td>
                            <td class="table-light"><a href="{{action('LocationController@downloadfactures', ['numsoc' => $d->Soc,'numfact' => trim($d->FactureNum)])}}" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-files-o" title="duplicata"></i></a></td>
                            <td class="table-light"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-book" title="annexes" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                @else
                @endif
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/download/{numsoc}/{numfact}', 'LocationController@downloadfactures')->name('download');
```

error message :

Fatal error: Call to undefined function http_response_code() in **\api\loc\api.php on line 552

Comment: Could you show us the line that is pointed to by the error? (the topmost one)

Comment: i change the return data so i have a new error message, i edited the post

Comment: if it can help, i can see in my log files, 2 calls
2019-04-24 14:23:17 - GET downloadfacture /downloadfacture/2795 numsoc=12&numfact=1218100300
2019-04-24 14:23:17 - GET downloadfacture /downloadfacture/

Comment: problem solved! it was the return statement! i update the right method. Thanks for your times :)